# How to connect text change event in multiple text boxes to a single method (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I double click on my text boxes in the designed, it creates a method auto-magically for me. Since I wish the same things to occur in any of the cases, I simply call an auxiliary method from each, like in the code below.

```
private void TextBox_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextChanged();
}

private void TextBox_2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextChanged();
}

private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

Now I'd like to know if there's a way (other than going into my design file (which, according to the information in it, shouldn't be attempted to) to connect the actions listeners to the same method and skip the detour via the automatically generated ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties fold-out (most often to the right of your screen) you should have a thunder icon. That's where all the events are referable.

If you don't see the properties, select the regarded component (the text box in your case), right-mouse it and pick "properties" in the context menu.

Answer (score 3):

On the designer page go to the events tab, find the event you are looking for (TextChanged) and manually enter the name of the event handler you wish them all to use.

Answer (score 3):

I usually proceed like this in my projects, *if* controls are not going to change at runtime (i.e. if all controls in the form are added at design time):

```
// this is the container's ctor
public MyForm()
{
    TextBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(UniqueHandler);
    TextBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(UniqueHandler);
    ...
    TextBoxN.TextChange += new EventHandler(UniqueHandler);
}

void UniqueHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox source = (sender as TextBox);
    // handle the event!
}
```

If controls *will* change, it's actually quite similar, it just doesn't happen in the ctor but on-site:

```
// anywhere in the code
TextBox addedAtRuntime = new TextBox();
addedAtRuntime.TextChanged += new EventHandler(UniqueHandler);
MyForm.Controls.Add(addedAtRuntime);
// code goes on, the new textbox will share the handler
```

Comment: I see the set up and how it's supposed to work. However, for some reason, the even doesn't fire (or, rather, the method is not being called). `MyTexBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextInput);` should call `private void TextInput(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)`, shouldn't it?!

Comment: It should indeed. Do you see any errors, warnings ... ? Check you're not swallowing exceptions: (in Visual Studio menu) Debug -> Exceptions -> check 'thrown' in the 'common language runtime' row then try re-running. It *must* work if setup like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```
 void btn1_onchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Number One");
  }

  void btn1_onchange2(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MessageBox.Show("Number Two");
  }

  public MyForm() {


    Button btn1 = new Button();
    btn1.Text = "Click Me";
    this.Controls.Add(btn1);

    btn1.TextChange += new EventHandler(btn1_onchange);
    btn1.TextChange += new EventHandler(btn1_onchange2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in designer view. Instead of double-clicking on an element - go to your buttons' properties, select events tab and then put a proper handler name for adequate event. Voila!

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the InitializeComponent().
2. There are three events attached to each text box.

There you shoud be able to see the following.

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_TextChanged);
```

Replace this with

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

And then remove the method below

```
private void TextBox_2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextChanged();
}
```

Comment: I just Try to provide the solution becuase he have already generated the event and now he want the idae how can he do and this was the way he can do it.